# Symfony2 - crash after add RoutingAutoBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-cmf

I have next problem with cmf bundle.
I created my own cms on routing bundle and everything work fine.
I want to add blog to my cms so I installed RoutingAutoBundle and after that 
( without any configuration ). I just adding it to AppKernel.

When I run homepage I get an error :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0
```

When I try to run some page /about-us I get this same error but it is linked with :

```
{{ path(cmf_find('/cms/routes')) }}
{{ knp_menu_render('main-menu'}) }}
```

in my twig file

my cmf_route :

```
cmf_routing:
    chain:
        routers_by_id:
            router.default: 200
            cmf_routing.dynamic_router: 100
    dynamic:
        persistence:
            phpcr:
                enabled: true
                route_basepaths:   
                    - /cms/routes
```

Anyone can help me? Anyone have similar problem?

Comment: Thank you, but I only wrong copy it. It doesn't resolve my problem. I have to add that routingAutoBundle work fine, but my menu and old routes don't.

Comment: I would assume you are the same Micchaleq that opened https://github.com/symfony-cmf/RoutingAutoBundle/issues/154 - lets discuss this in one location. github is more convenient for it.